# LibGDX Gradle Language Level Keeps resetting

Tags: gradle, libgdx, nightly-build

Before I ask, I have looked around and I do not see any other questions with similar problems as I, Currently I'm using the nightly build of LibGDX with Gradle and everytime I try to set the java language level to 7.0 or even 8.0 it refreshes gradle and then forces the language level back to 6.0, everything i read states that gradle has no control over the language level, yet that's when it forces a change, is there something that I am over looking? I've tried using File | Project Structure | Project Language Level, I've tried setting each module to 7.0 and I've tried setting the default language level for intellij, only reason I need 7.0 is for the ability to use the string type for a switch case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the language level in the Gradle build script (e.g. `sourceCompatibility = 1.7`).

Comment: I saw that, everything I read said that didn't work, but a few hours after i posted that I got it to work, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: would seem that intellij still keeps resetting the language level back to 6.0, btw I'm using java 8 if that helps

Comment: Not sure what's going on then, never had this problem. Perhaps raise this on the IntelliJ forums. Also you'd need to provide more information (how exactly are you creating the IntelliJ project, which IntelliJ version, which Gradle version, etc.).

Comment: will have to ask there, if i cancel the refresh the code builds fine, but next time i load intellij it asks to refresh the project

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem since you set the language level in Gradle. Perhaps LibGDX does something special there.

Comment: I think this is related : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65297
(I have the same problem)

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting a similar problem with trying to use Java 8 for a desktop-only build. I had to add the following to the desktop and core sections to get it working:

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and no luck with setting "sourceCompatibility". 
Apparently the sourceCompatibility attribute is usually used in conjunction with the gradle Java plugin. However libGDX uses the gradle Android plugin and then it should be used a little differently:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7

In the 'android' section of the gradle build script, add:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

This solved the problem for me anyway.